# Lookup table with best match query

Tags: sql, postgresql

To lookup a country for a phone number prefix I running the following query:

```
SELECT country_id 
FROM phonenumber_prefix 
WHERE '<myphonnumber>' LIKE prefix ||'%' 
ORDER BY LENGTH(calling_prefix) DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

To query phone numbers from a table I run a query like:

```
SELECT phonenumber 
FROM phonenumbers
```

Now I want to combine those query into one, to get countries for all phone numbers. I know that I could put the first query into a function e.g. getCountry() and then query

```
SELECT phonenumber, getCountry(phonenumber) 
FROM phonenumbers
```

But is there also a way to to do this with joins in one query, I'm using postgresql 9.2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT phonenumber,
       (SELECT country_id 
        FROM phonenumber_prefix pp
        WHERE pn.phonenumber LIKE prefix ||'%' 
        ORDER BY LENGTH(calling_prefix) DESC 
        LIMIT 1
       ) as country_id
FROM phonenumbers pn;
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you list of numbers with corresponding country ids for the longest matching prefix:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT 
    p.phonenumber, pc.country_id, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY phonenumber ORDER BY LENGTH(pc.prefix) DESC) rn
  FROM 
    phonenumber_prefix pc INNER JOIN
    phonenumbera p ON p.phonenumber LIKE pc.prefix || '%' ) t
WHERE t.rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using a join as so:

```
select phonenumber, countryId
from phonenumbers
inner join phonenumber_prefix on phonenumber like prefix||'%'
```

Be aware that this will be quite inefficient though as it won't be able to use indexes for the join.

You can also do it the other way around (by extracting the correct number of digits from the start of the phone number). That will improve things a bit as it will be able to use an index to look up the prefix, but it will still need to split each phonenumber.